# Noob in Ruby - is there diff between " " and ' ' after puts

Tags: ruby, difference, puts

I have one beginner question for Ruby. I have been practicing Ruby with Chris Pine book and I see that he sometimes uses ' ' and sometimes " " after puts method.

Now, I have realized that I cant put any variable with # { } if I use ' ' since I have tried that , and also, if I use for example " " I don't have to discount ' with backslash like this \' (and other way around) but other than that I don't know are there any major differences between these to things or in other words should I sometimes use exclusively ' ' and sometimes " " ?

Tnx

Comment: I'd recommend reading "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". We don't care if you're new, we expect you to do your research, to try, and to show what you tried in a concise, well-asked question. Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" will help you also.

Comment: Ok sorry, it was a language barrier. I was trying to search with signs "" and '', forgot it was called single/double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two differences:

1. String interpolation: Double quotes allow it, single quotes won't.

   For example:

   ```
   name = "SrdjaNo1"

   puts "Hi #{name}!"
   #=> Hi SrdjaNo1!

   puts 'Hi #{name}!'
   #=> Hi #{name}!
   ```
2. Escaping sequences: Single quotes will print them as text.

   For example:

   ```
   puts "Hello \nworld!"
   #=> Hello
   #=> world!

   puts 'Hello \nworld!'
   #=> Hello \nworld!
   ```

Other than that, you could use any of them, just **be consistent** with its use throughout your code.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for the catch, already updated answer.